# Gradle project produces compiler errors for Java 7/8 API references, through gradle appears to be using JDK 8 correctly

Tags: java, scala, gradle, java-8

I have a gradle project that is to be built against JDK 1.8, but I get compiler errors like `error: value lineSeparator is not a member of object System` and `error: not found: type AutoCloseable`. Doesn't this indicate that my project is being built with a JDK older than 1.7? Yet I have tried:

- building from the command line with `gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71" build`
- `gradlew -v` shows `JVM:          1.8.0_71 (Oracle Corporation 25.71-b15)`
- gradle.properties in the project folder has `org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_71`
- There is no .gradle/gradle.properties file in my user home folder that would override the setting
- Built from IntelliJ IDEA with JDK 1.8 set in the project options and default options
- My build.gradle looks like:

`

```
group = 'net.joelbecker'
version = '2.0.0'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
//apply plugin: 'java'

project.sourceCompatibility = 1.8
project.targetCompatibility = 1.8


allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

println System.getProperty("java.home")

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'net.joelbecker'
            artifactId 'util'
            version '2.0.0'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7'
    compile 'xstream:xstream:1.2.2'
    compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.16'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.4.3'

    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:2.2.6'
}
```

The source code is scala, though I don't know that that would make a difference.

(Thanks in advance)

Comment: Scala is not compiled with the java compiler, so it will definitely make a difference. The `ScalaCompile` task seems to default to [`project.targetCompatibility`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.scala.ScalaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.scala.ScalaCompile:targetCompatibility) though and shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: I succeeded by creating a new gradle project from scratch through IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1, carefully choosing the JDKs through the wizard, and also setting Project Structure (F4) -> Project Settings -> Modules -> [module name] -> Sources tab -> Language level . (Though I then tried that same last setting on the original project without success, so still don't know the root cause)